# Could not find package flutter_localization in the Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-localizations

I am currently trying to implement localization in my Flutter App but whenever I try to add the dependency for `flutter_localization`, I get the following error Message:

> Because the timer depends on `flutter_localization` from SDK which doesn't exist (could not find package `flutter_localization` in the Flutter SDK), version solving failed.

I have also correctly added the path to both my flutter and dart SDKs in Android Studio.

Here is my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  sqflite: any
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  path_provider: any
  flutter_localization:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

I can't access GlobalMaterialLocalizations without flutter_localization and apparently, this is the easiest solution. I have already tried many solutions like checking version compatibilities and updating all dependencies. can you guys help me out?

Thanks in Advance!

Upgrading SDKs, Upgrading Dependencies, reinstalling flutter and Dart, and more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You misspelled the package

Replace

```
 flutter_localization:
    sdk: flutter
```

With

```
 flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Take note on the **s** on **flutter_localizations**